# If String contains either one of two words with IgnoreCase

Tags: java, string, contains, ignore-case

I have a program where the user should be able to type how many degrees, and in what scale (Celsius, Fahrenheit or Kelvin). If the user wish to quit the session, the program should quit if they write "Exit, EXIT, exit, QUIT, Quit or quit". I know how to do the code with only one of these at a time, such as:

```
System.out.println("Enter your value, followed by the unit (C/F/K) : ");
temp=input.nextLine();

if (temp.contains("exit")) {
    System.out.println("Ending");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

I want to be able to write something like: 
if (temp.containsIgnoreCase("exit" || "quit") )

Can anybody help me with some guidelines to how I should fix my code? I have tried to search for it here but nothing has really worked, I only get errors when I have two different words inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 5):

Try lowercasing the user input and then comparing with `String#matches`:

```
if (temp.toLowerCase().matches("exit|quit")) {
    System.out.println("Ending");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use matches to find exact match with string . you can like this:

```
 String quit = "quit";
    String exit = "exit";
    if(temp.toLowerCase().matches(quit)||temp.toLowerCase().matches(exit)){
            System.out.println("Ending");
System.exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tim Biegeleisen answers is probably the way to go. If you, like myself just prefer not to use `String.toLowerCase()`. You could use `Pattern#compile(String, int)` with a case insensitive flag instead:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("exit|quit", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
if(pattern.matcher(temp).matches()){
    System.out.println("ending");
    System.exit(0);
}
```